# How to substitute intra-word hyphens when hyphens surround a single inner character

Tags: regex, r, text, replace

I want to preserve intra-word hyphens in text prior to tokenizing it.  The strategy involves substituting the hyphens for a unique character, then replacing that unique character with hyphens after tokenizing.  Note: I'll ultimately use the Unicode class of `Pd` to catch all forms of dash character, but here I'm keeping it simple since I don't think that part is pertinent to the problem.

Problem: It fails when a word contains multiple inner hyphens separating a single character.

Examples and desired outcomes:

```
replaceDash <- function(x) gsub("(\\w)-(\\w)", "\\1§\\2", x)

# these are all OK
replaceDash("Hawaii-Five-O")  
## [1] "Hawaii§Five§O"
replaceDash("jack-of-all-trades")  
## [1] "jack§of§all§trades"
replaceDash("A-bomb")         
## [1] "A§bomb"
replaceDash("freakin-A")      
## [1] "freakin§A"

# not the desired outcome
replaceDash("jack-o-lantern")  # FAILS - should be "jack§o§lantern"
## [1] "jack§o-lantern"
replaceDash("Whack-a-Mole")    # FAILS - should be "Whack§a§Mole"
## [1] "Whack§a-Mole"
```

What regex patterns do I need for the first and second expressions of the `gsub()`?

Comment: Please post some more input strings that need to be changed, one might come as well up with a solution that works without replacing anything before.

Comment: What about `gsub("(\\b)-(\\b)", "\\1§\\2", "jack-o-lantern")`?

Comment: What about `gsub("(?<=\\w)-(?=\\w)", "§", "jack-o-lantern",perl=T)`

Comment: Try `gsub("(\\w)-(?=\\w)", "\\1§", "jack-o-lantern", perl=T)`. No need using a lookbehind, BTW, since it is rather a costly subpattern. See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iJruQ7)

Comment: Nice solutions, all work! And the explanation is very useful. Any reason to use this version over @lukeA's simpler suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a PCRE regex with a look-ahead that would check if a word character appears right after a hyphen, but would not *consume* it.

```
replaceDash <- function(x) gsub("(\\w)-(?=\\w)", "\\1§", x, perl=T)
```

See [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/iJruQ7)

So, `(\\w)` captures an alphanumeric symbol into Group 1 that is later inserted into the replacement result with the help of `\\1` backreference, and with `(?=\\w)` we only make sure there is a word character, but the regex index stays at the hyphen, thus allowing the next match from that word character.

Answer (score -1):

you did not specify what kind of regex capabilities are allowed.  Here is a pattern using zero-with look around:

```
gsub("(?<=\\w)-(?=\\w)", "§", "jack-o-lantern");
# jack§o§trade
```

Comment: You posted someone else's suggestion without explanation. Not fair.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew please post your answer it's nice :)

Comment: @NicE: It takes time to write a post :)

Comment: yes indeed it takes time to write a post. My post was simultaneaous with the other suggestion.  But indeed, yours is even better.